# How do you import Javascript file from node_modules into react using Vite?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, pdf.js, react-pdf

How do you load a static asset from node_modules in my case pdf.js (from the build folder of node_modules) so I don't have to set the version every time I update it.

I am migrating from Webpack to Vite, so this is how I use it in my webpack project currently.

```js
<Worker workerUrl="/pdf.worker.bundle.js">
```

Webpack configuration

```js
'pdf.worker': path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js'),
```

Looking for the Vite equivalent

My Vite configuration file is no different from the stock one.

##### Things I tried:

- I looked at doing a service worker, but that seems more complex than what I'm looking for.

Comment: you don't, you bundle it in? Your code has an import (which node resolves from node_modules) and your bundler will take all the code you _actually_ use, and bundle it up into a single (or chunked) deliverable. The fact that there ever was a `node_modules` dir is 100% irrelevant.

Comment: I need to pass a URL for worker url in though, so how would I use an import here?

Comment: Ah. If you need a worker, then you define a second webpack build for specifically creating your worker bundle with a different entry point and output filepath. (which you can either do in the same config file, or you can create a different config file and run that as part of building as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a URL rather than a worker, my solution was just to import the javascript file from node modules. Vite will handle this

```js
import WorkerPdfJsUrl from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker?url'

<Worker workerUrl={WorkerPdfJsUrl} >
  <div
    style={{
      height: '750px',
      width: '900px',
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
    }}
  >
    <Viewer
      theme='light'
      fileUrl={pdfFile}
      plugins={[defaultLayoutPluginInstance]}
    />
  </div>
</Worker>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only in dev mode. After the app is being compiled, I'm getting 404 error when `react-pdf` tries to refer the `node_modules`

Comment: I noticed that too, so what I did is change the import to something similar what is shown below. I'll edit my answer too

Comment: Thank you, William! I didn't know about the `?url` import type in Vite 

Answer (score 1):

You can import a script as a Web Worker by appending [`?worker`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-script-as-a-worker) to the import path:

```js
import PdfJsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js?worker'
const worker = new PdfJsWorker()
```

No config is needed.

Comment: I tried `<PDFWorker>
        {/* https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/examples/compile-and-set-the-worker-source-with-webpack/ */}
        <div
          className="pdfViewer__container"
        >
          <Viewer
            fileUrl={pdfFile}
            plugins={[defaultLayoutPluginInstance]}
          />
        </div>
      </PDFWorker>`

but react is complaining about it not being a valid JSX element

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me!

`import { Document, Page, DocumentProps, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';`
`import PdfJsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js?worker';`
`const pdfJsWorker = new PdfJsWorker();`
`pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = pdfJsWorker;`

Comment: Now the PDFs are displayed, but I'm getting another error in the console: `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'pdfjsWorker') at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition`